# MongoDB aggregation '$sortBy' using combination of fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with fields ***sender*** and ***receiver*** and I want to perform a group by aggregation on the collection with the fields ***sender*** and ***receiver***.

Example

collection:

```
[
  { "id": 1, "sender": "A", "receiver": "B"},
  { "id": 3, "sender": "B", "receiver": "A"},
  { "id": 4, "sender": "B", "receiver": "C"},
  { "id": 5, "sender": "C", "receiver": "A"}
]
```

Expected aggregated output will be:

```
[
  { "_id": { "user1": "A", "user2": "B"}, "total": 2 },
  { "_id": { "user1": "A", "user2": "C"}, "total": 1 },
  { "_id": { "user1": "B", "user2": "C"}, "total": 1 },
]
```

Is this possible by using MongoDB aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$addFields`: Add `users` field with an array of `sender` and `receiver`.
2. [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/): Deconstruct array field `users` for sorting in Step 3.
3. `$sort`: Sort deconstructed `users` array from Step 2 in alphabetical order.
4. `$group`: Group by `id` to construct `users` to the array.
5. `$group`: Group by `user1` and `user2` for total with `$count`.
6. `$sort`: Sort `_id.user1` and `_id.user2` in alphabetical order.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "users": [
        "$sender",
        "$receiver"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$users"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "users": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$id",
      "users": {
        $push: "$users"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "user1": {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            "$users",
            0
          ]
        },
        "user2": {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            "$users",
            1
          ]
        }
      },
      "total": {
        $count: {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id.user1": 1,
      "_id.user2": 1
    }
  }
])
```

> Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "user1": "A",
      "user2": "B"
    },
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "user1": "A",
      "user2": "C"
    },
    "total": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "user1": "B",
      "user2": "C"
    },
    "total": 1
  }
]
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B9eKASNUS6X)